# Why is $\arg(i\cosh x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-functions

I was told $\arg(i\cosh (x))=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\arg(\cosh (x))=0$ but I can't figure out why. Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: $\arg(iR)$ should be $\frac\pi2$, if $R$ is _any_ positive real number. Similarly, $\arg(R)$ should be $0$ for any positive real number. Hint: try drawing where $iR$ and $R$ are in the complex plane. ("Where $iR$ and $R$ are" makes quite a tongue twister...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I assume $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $cosh(x)>0$ is a real number.

Since argument of $z$ is the angle from the positive real axis to the vector representing $z$, thus $i\cosh(x)$ has $\frac{\pi}{2}$ as argument and $\cosh(x)$ has $0$ as argument. More precisely, here "argument" means principal argument.